# Cannot resolve Symbol AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: flutter, dart, android-manifest

I have thre Problems with my AndroidManifest.xml.

1. Cannot resolve symbol '@mipmap/ic_launcher'
2. Cannot resolve symbol '@style/LaunchTheme'
3. Cannot resolve symbol '@style/NormalTheme'

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.moneyreminder"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="5.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
         />
   <application
        android:label="moneyreminder"

        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            tools:ignore="Instantiatable"
            tools:targetApi="honeycomb">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"


              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I tried to invalidate Caches but it changed nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have all these folders in your project **android/app/src/main/res** folder ?

[image]

If not create them and add their resources.

**values-v31/style.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: I don't have mipmap-anydpi-v26 and values-v31. May you send me those folders? Thank you

Comment: I don't think you need those one. I have  nothing in my **mipmap-anydpi-v26** folder, but I just added the content of **values-v31/style.xml** file to my answer anyway.

Comment: Do you have lines containing `name="LaunchTheme"` and `name="NormalTheme"` in your styles.xml files? Eg: _<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"><!-- ... --></style>_.

Comment: yes I have does. <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" and <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">

Comment: What IDE are you using and do you get the error when you try to run the app or it's just the IDE who is showing the error?

Comment: I use Android studios and it is only the IDE that is showing the error. When I run the app it's perfectly fine but the problem is that I have launched my app on the Play Store but I get an error when I try to download it. So I started to search for problems in my code.

Comment: If it's just Android Studio problem, I think you can ignore it, it happens sometimes but I don't really know cause that (I have looked through stackoverflow but didn't really find the right answer). What error do you get when you try to download the app?

Comment: "Money Reminder" cannot be installed
try again If the problem persists, here are some common solutions

Comment: I searched through Play store to find your app and try it but there are so much apps (most are just related to the name). The only one I found with that name (before I got bored of searching) is from _company of dreams_. Can you send me a link to get it ?

Comment: you have found the right one https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.muellerniklas.moneyreminder&hl=de

Comment: I downloaded and installed it, and it's working fine (I'm testing on android 7.1.1 though). The only problem is that when I try to add debt and click **Send**, nothing happen.

Comment: Thats interesting because I changed nothing. Now I will work on the "Send" Problem. Thanks for your help.